# Unable to connect JDBC to sonarqube using Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, sonarqube

When I am installing sonarqube using postgresql, I got stuck with connecting it to jdbc of Postgresql. In `/opt/sonarqube/conf`, I uncommented JDBC as

```
sonar.jdbc.username=username
sonar.jdbc.password=password.
2.sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/username
```

Additionally, below is my sonar scanner conf that I uncommented
Default SonarQube server

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
PostgreSQL
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/username
```

This is what I followed for configuring [Postgres DB](https://gist.github.com/RawToast/feab6b36d2592554d071)

This is my log file shows

> 2017.03.08 14:39:13 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/username
>   2017.03.08 14:39:13 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
>           at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:104) ~[sonar-db-5.6.6.jar:na]

Is there any other thing that I need to do for JDBC connection of Postgresql. is there is any document available for sonarqube for postgresql.

Comment: Have you tried to connect directly to the database using your configuration ?

Comment: Hi Juline, I thought postgres qill be like MySQL when configuring with sonarqube. I missed one of the step which is `[root@sonarqube ~]# egrep "^local|^host" /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5`  this step helped me to solve my JDBC issue. Thanks for your response @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: For connecting Sonarqube to postgres which is a JDBC connection, this is the very important step

`[root@sonarqube ~]# egrep "^local|^host" /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5`

we need to uncomment in the above path so that JDBC can get work

Comment: You should make this last comment an Answer. You should spend more time before you coome to SO. You were able to work this one out yourself. When you need to ask a question, find a colleague who doesn't know about the tools you use. Just ask the question to them. No Q&A between you. Then ask them to explain what they understood of your question. If they can understand your question, it's good enough to ask. If not, you need to improve the question. At times, you'll find that the preparation of the information and the process of presenting it logically gets you the answer anyway. Rep came back.

Comment: Done @ Bill Woodger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got worked out for me
`[root@sonarqube ~]# egrep "^local|^host" /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf
uncomment below lines in pg_hba.conf
 local all all md5
 host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5 
host all all ::1/128 md5`