# sonarqube didn't run web UI (java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost)

Tags: java, postgresql, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Ubuntu 14
Sonar 6.7.1
Postgresql 9.5
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)

Sonarqube didn't run web UI but sonar service was active. Could you help me
java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost

/opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/logs/web.log

```
ERROR web[][o.postgresql.Driver] Connection error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:275)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1617)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.ensureMinIdle(GenericObjectPool.java:1575)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.access$700(GenericObjectPool.java:190)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1709)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:68)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
```

/opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/logs/sonar.log

```
2018.01.31 16:37:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp
2018.01.31 16:37:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.01.31 16:37:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp/conf/es
2018.01.31 16:37:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.01.31 16:37:21 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.01.31 16:37:21 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.01.31 16:37:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2018.01.31 16:37:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonarqube-6.7.1]: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain= -DsocksProxyHost= -DsocksProxyPort= -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort= -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.1.4.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp/sq-process3048603911980736431properties
2018.01.31 16:40:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2018.01.31 16:40:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.01.31 16:40:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2018.01.31 16:40:27 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
```

Sonar.properties config

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
sonar.web.port=9000
```

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681411/unable-to-connect-jdbc-to-sonarqube-using-postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was in the driver jdbc in sonar lib for posrgesql. Version 42.1.6 doesn't work. I downloaded 42.2.1 and change name with ver. "...42.1.6.jar". Yes it's wrong but it's work.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the error message during connecting postgres db, and my issue was successfully fixed after upgrading `org.postgresqlpostgresql` dependency